# How to check if a statevector is made of product of EPR pairs in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, entanglement

I have a **statevector of 10 qubits**. I want to check if the qubits 0,1 and 2,3 are EPR pairs/Bell pairs. The other qubits (4,5,6,7,8,9) have been measured.

There are [four possible 2-qubit states that are Bell pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state#Bell_basis).
I created circuits for all possible tensor products of these 4 states with the following code (total 16 states):

```
num_qubits = 10

#measurement_string contains the measurement values of qubits 4,5,6,7,8,9
#example:measurement_string  = 001010 means q4 was measured = 0,q5 = 0, q6 = 1, q7 = 0,q8 = 1, q9 = 0

def epr_product_1(measurement_string):
  #first entangled pair
  qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
  qc.h(0)
  qc.cx(0,1)

  #second entangled pair
  qc.h(1)
  qc.cx(2,3)

  #qubits 4,5,6,7,8,9 were measured as either 0 or 1, create the circuit accordingly
  for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
    if s == '1':
        qc.x(index + 4)

  return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_2(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.x(0)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(2)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
    
        
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_1_2(measurement_string):
    #firdt entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(2)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
    
        
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)

def epr_product_2_1(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(0)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)
    
    
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
    
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_3(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)

def epr_product_4(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    
    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.z(0)
    qc.z(1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.z(2)
    qc.z(3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)

def epr_product_3_4(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.z(2)
    qc.z(3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_4_3(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)
    qc.z(0)
    qc.z(1)
    
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)
    qc.cx(2,3)
        
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_1_3(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)
    
    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
    
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_3_1(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)
    
    # Apply a CNOT
    qc.cx(0,1)
    
    
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2, 3)    
        
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_2_3(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.x(0)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
            
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_3_2(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)


    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)
    
    
    qc.x(2)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
    
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_1_4(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.z(2)
    qc.z(3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_4_1(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)
    qc.z(0)
    qc.z(1)
    
    
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_2_4(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)
    
    qc.x(0)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.cx(0,1)

    #second entangled pair
    qc.x(3)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.z(2)
    qc.z(3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)


def epr_product_4_2(measurement_string):
    #first entangled pair
    qc = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

    qc.x(1)
    qc.h(0)

    qc.z(0)
    qc.z(1)
    
    
    qc.x(2)
    qc.h(2)

    qc.cx(2,3)
                
    for index,s in enumerate(measurement_string):
        if s == '1':
            qc.x(index + 4)
            
    return Statevector.from_instruction(qc)
```

Then I compared the statevectors obtained from the above circuit with the statevector that I have(called 'my_state_vec' in code) using the **equiv** function:

```
def check_epr_pairs():

    measurement = '010101'

    epr_products = []
    epr_products.append(epr_product_1(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_2(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_3(measurement))

    epr_products.append(epr_product_4(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_1_2(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_1_3(measurement))

    epr_products.append(epr_product_1_4(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_2_1(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_2_3(measurement))

    epr_products.append(epr_product_2_4(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_3_1(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_3_2(measurement))

    epr_products.append(epr_product_3_4(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_4_1(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_4_2(measurement))
    epr_products.append(epr_product_4_3(measurement))

    for ep in epr_products:
        #Check if statevectors are equivalent
        if my_state_vec.equiv(ep):
            print("Statevec equivalent with", ep)
```

I have theoretical reason to believe that my_state_vec should be such that qubits 0,1 and 2,3 are EPR pairs. But I find that it is not equivalent to any of the EPR product statevectors.

The statevector produced by the qubits 0,1,2,3 is:
\begin{bmatrix}-0.25\\
-0.25\\
0.25\\
0.25\\
0.25\\
0.25\\
0.25\\
0.25\\
0.25\\
-0.25\\
-0.25\\
0.25\\
-0.25\\
0.25\\
-0.25\\
0.25\end{bmatrix}

**Is there a better way of checking for EPR pair products?**

Comment: A high-level suggestion. To see if qubits A and B form an EPR pair (1) compute density matrix of the two-qubit system AB. It should have rank 1, i.e. be a pure state. (2) compute the density matrix of A alone, it should be an identity matrix if A and B form a Bell pair.

Comment: @NikitaNemkov I tried this suggestion. Step (1) checked out and AB is a pure state.  Step (2), I get the density matrix of A as a diagonal matrix (all diagonal entries = 0.5). So this suggests, AB don't form a bell pair?

Comment: I also updated the question (added the resultant statevector of the 4 qubits)

Comment: I didn't look at your statevector, but diagonal matrix with entries 0.5 sounds exactly right. Actually, a density matrix can not be an identity because it must have unit trace. So, saying that $\rho$ is an identity is often a jargon for $\rho=\mathbb{I}/2^n$.